# Phusion passenger can't free port

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

Ok, i'm running passenger standalone, and made a dumb mistake, now I need help fixing.

So a test app directory was running standalone passenger on a specific port, and I deleted the directory so that I could pull a new app in place of it (and use the same port). Well, not thinking about passenger at all, I should have stopped the daemon first. Well, now the port is tied up somewhere, and I cannot figure out for the life of me how to stop it. I found the process that the port started on, and killed it, but to no avail. The address is still bound and unusable.

Short of restarting the server (not really a viable solution for me), how can I kill that nginx / passenger process all together so that I can start a new instance of passenger on that port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passenger Standalone starts Nginx for you, and that is what is actually bound to the port. Because you deleted the directory, Passenger Standalone cannot access Nginx's lock file or PID file, and that's why upon killing Passenger Standalone it could cannot kill Nginx for you. You should kill Nginx manually.

Comment: I guess thats what I'm asking how to do. Any ideas on how to find out which PID i need to kill? I've got a number of nginx instances running on the box.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was able to find the process with lsof -i :portnumber
thanks for the help

Comment: You can also just use `ps auxw | grep nginx`.

Answer (score 2):

Run `lsof -i :portnumber` e.g. `lsof -i :3000`

You will get something like this ...

```
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
Passenger 10514 USERNAME    5u  IPv4 0xea95336b89bfa931      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
Passenger 10515 USERNAME    5u  IPv4 0xea95336b89bfa931      0t0  TCP *:hbci (LISTEN)
```

Stop the processes using `kill PID` ... something like `kill 10514`